# JQUERY / Adding Elements to a DIV iterating over an array only stores the last element

Tags: jquery, html, append

I receive a JSON array which is parsed and each element will be placed into a DIV by iterating that array using the each method of Jquery, the problem is that the DIV only stores the last element.

Here is the code:

```
//I receive a JSON array via AJAX and then I parse it
    var arreglo=$.parseJSON(respuesta);
    $('#resultadoBusqueda').addClass('divNoEscondido')
    //Then I iterate over the array to insert each value and each key as an individual element
    $.each(arreglo,function(key,value){
        $('#resultadoBusqueda').append('h1').text(key);
        $('#resultadoBusqueda').append('h1').text(value);
// The problem is that the div that receives the new elements only stores the last one
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new `h1` elements for each item in the array so

```
var arreglo = $.parseJSON(respuesta);
var $ct = $('#resultadoBusqueda').addClass('divNoEscondido')
//Then I iterate over the array to insert each value and each key as an individual element
$.each(arreglo, function (key, value) {
    $('<h1/>', {
        text: key
    }).appendTo($ct)
    $('<h1/>', {
        text: value
    }).appendTo($ct)
})
```

What you are doing is to, append the text `h1` to `#resultadoBusqueda`, then override the entire content of `#resultadoBusqueda` with the key of the current item then with the value of the current item, so at the end of the loop, only the value of the last item in the loop is visible to you.

Comment: I did the following code and now the program adds twice the same last value

div = $('#resultadoBusqueda')
 //Then I iterate over the array to insert each value and each key as an individual element
 $.each(arreglo,function(key,value){
  elemento1=$('h1').text(key);
  div.append(elemento1);
  elemento2=$('h1').text(value);
  div.append(elemento2);
// The problem is that the div that receives the new elements only stores the last one
  })

Comment: God! I was Missing the brackets when declaring the h1 , I was typping 'h1' instead '<h1>', thanks Arun!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery append method return the container. so you should write code like this:

```
$('#resultadoBusqueda').append('h1');
$('#resultadoBusqueda h1').text(key);
```